# No mapping for GET /resources/views/home.jsp in Spring Boot app with @EnableWebMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**@EnableWebMvc** breaks default mappings provided by auto-configuration, so I have added **InternalResourceViewResolver**, but this didn't help me to get view. When I enter:

```
http://localhost:8090/logIn
```

I get this message in the console:

```
No mapping for GET /resources/views/home.jsp
```

Maybe `DispatcherServlet` mapped to `/*`, if yes how to change mapping to `/` for embedded `dispatcherServlet`.

Project Structure:

```
main  
 +- java  
 |    +- app
 |        +- Application.java  
 |        +- web
 |            +- LogInController.java
 |        +- config
 |            +- ViewResolverConfig.java    
 +- resources
      +- views
          +- home.jsp
      +- application.properties
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ViewResolverConfig.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

ViewResolverConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ViewResolverConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("resources/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

LogInController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/logIn")
public class LogInController  {

    @GetMapping
    public String enterPage(Model model){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters I strongly would suggest NOT to use JSP with Spring Boot as there are severe limitations and the technology is dated, you are better of using something like THymeleaf. That being said, your `prefix` property is wrong. Remove the `resources/` part and even then it will probably fail (due to the limitations mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations))

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, unfortunately it fails with suggested fix. I get view with Thymeleaf and home.html in `resources/templates/`. But I don't get static `welcome.html` from `resources/static` with resource handler, which path pattern is `/static/**` and having `classpath:/static/` in resource locations. I use `return "static/welcome.html"` in my controller. My app with described configuration successfully serving `resources/static/style.css`. I would very much appreciate, if you give me advice about serving static pages.

Comment: Views returned from the controller are passed on to the `ViewResolver`. You shouldn't have a controller for static pages. Also you should remove the `ViewResolverConfig` class as all of that is already done by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. I understand. What is right way to implement same behavior, which gives me controller with `if (isUserCredentialsValid()) { return "redirect:static/welcome.html"; } else { return "logIn"; }`

Comment: Don't use a controller for that use a Filter. Also you don't want to implement your own security use Spring Security instead.